# ATL Link Warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, atl, wtl

When I create a new Win32 Project (Windows application) in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with ATL headers, the merely inclusion of `<atlbase.h>` gives me this warning:

```
TempATL.obj : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
```

When I also include `<atlapp.h>` from WTL, I get these additional warnings:

```
atlsd.lib(Externs.obj) : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
atlsd.lib(AtlDebugAPI.obj) : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
atlsd.lib(Allocate.obj) : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
atlsd.lib(atltrace.obj) : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
atlsd.lib(AtlTraceModuleManager.obj) : warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
```

What is the proper way resolve these warnings?

---

#### Edit:

I just found that these are happening because I'd switched Visual Studio 2008 to use the Visual C++ **2010** compilers with the 2008 *libraries*. If someone knows how to fix this **other** than by switching back to the older compilers, then please post. :)

Comment: These warnings do not accompany any ATL/WTL build, there is something specific in your project which is causing this problem.

Comment: @RomanR.: I don't think so... I've created the projects from scratch, and while the WTL build is not an official release (it's a pull from the source control), I've certainly *not* modified ATL.

Comment: I did dozens of ATL/WTL builds over years and never had a chance to see these warnings. The warnings themselves suggest that the problem is with incompatible `.lib`s rather than source code itself.

Comment: @RomanR.: That's... really weird. I presume you've tried VC 2008 SP1 and 2010?

Comment: I actually tried 2002 through 2010 SP1

Comment: @RomanR.: I guess I'll try reinstalling the files then... thanks for the info.

Comment: @RomanR.: Ah... now I found something. See my update.

Comment: @Mehrdad Have you found solution to the issue ? I am getting the same while transitioning from VS 2005 to VS 2012 :(

Comment: @Mahesh: Nope, I've just ignored the warnings...

Comment: @Mehrdad If you have ignored, then I can too safely ignore :)

Comment: Mehrdad answered his own question with his edit.  This made me realize in my case I was including headers and libraries for VS2010 in my VS2012 project when I was upgrading the project.  I had downloaded a Windows Driver Development kit to provide these headers since VS2010 express didn't provide the necessary ATL headers; however VS2012 has newer versions provided, which are not backwards compatible with VS2010 for some reason.  So I just removed those includes and the warnings went away.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running the Express version of MSVC and using atl from the Windows SDK. To get rid of those warnings just add `/ignore:4254 /ignore:4078` to the additional command line options for the linker.

See: [ATL 8.0 included in WDK 7.1 makes the linker to generate almost eight hundred LNK4254...](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=commitdiff;h=b9e35854b4d2d7361b618d265ba8919013d285fb)

Comment: No, actually I have VS 2008 Pro.